# Inserting shape that saves with document (object required error)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with the code below. I previously had a functioning with the insert picture method, but the pictures weren't being saved with the document. Please ignore the sizing component, as I will have to adjust this when I get the code working.

The object required error occurs in the line of code marked with **.

I'm very new to VBA, so please explain in the most simplistic terms.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("IMG_FILE_ALL")) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
    Dim pic As String
        pic = Target.Offset(0, 0).Value

    Dim myPicture As Shape

      **Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:="C:\Users\wallacew\Pictures\Ex4.jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=rgTarget.Left, Top:=rgTarget.Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)**

    Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range(Target.Offset(0, 0), Target.Offset(12, 1))

    With myPicture
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = 333
        .Top = rng.Top + 3
        .Left = rng.Left + 3
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Try `Dim myPicture as Object`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: What is `rgTarget` ? You did not declare or set it here. Maybe You meant just `Target` ?